# Cant run a web request in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to run the following in Powershell

```
  Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $exportUrl -Method Post -Headers $headers -Body $body
```

But keep getting the error;

```
  Invoke-WebRequest : {"error":{"code":"InvalidSubscriptionId","message":"The provided 
  subscription identifier '{subscriptionId}' is malformed or invalid."}}
```

Any ideas on what is causing this ?

Comment: This is an error from the website you're interacting with, not from PowerShell. Without additional information/context, we can't really help you figure out why you're getting this error but I'd recommend you find the documentation for whatever website you're querying to figure out why it's giving you that error

Comment: This is a shot in the dark, but based on the error message you probably need to replace the literal string ```{subscriptionId}``` in your url with the actual subscription id that you're interested in. Failing that, as @jeremywat says, check the documentation for the api you're hitting...

Comment: changed that and now it says:    Invoke-WebRequest : {"error":{"details":[{"code":"InvalidResourceIdSegment","message":"","target":"parameters"}],"code":"InvalidResourceIdSegment","message":"The 'parameters' segment in the url is invalid."}}

Comment: @Melissa only you can tell what's wrong here - we can't see your screen or telepathically read your source code. Either [consult the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/troubleshooting/error-invalid-name-segments) for the system you're working with, or share enough information so that others can reproduce the issue (eg. show us the actual data you're sending to the API)